# I can't get my VBA Excel Macro to stop at the end of the row

Tags: excel, vba

I have a row of data that changes once a month but it only changes roughly 30 cells out of 90 and every month they are different so I am trying to make a Macro to automate it.

The Macro looks at Cells A2 - B98 and searches for information that matches the Values of H2-I98 and if the values in A match H then it copies what the value is in I and replaces it in B but it doest stop at the end of the row i.e. at row 98 it loops infinatly. So I was hoping someone could find my error so that it wont loop for ever. Thanks

```
Sub Update_Holiday()

Dim Search As String
Dim Replacement As String
Dim rngTmp As Range
Dim rngSearch As Range

LastInputRow = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
Set rngSearch = Worksheets("Holiday").Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(98, 2))

For k = 2 to 98
    Search = Worksheets("Holiday").Cells(k, 8)
    Replacement = Worksheets("Holiday").Cells(k, 9)
    With rngSearch
        Set rngTmp = .Find(Search, LookIn:=xlValues)
        If rngTmp Is Nothing Then
            GoTo Go_to_next_input_row: 
        Else
            Worksheets("Holiday").Cells(rngTmp.Row, rngTmp.Column + 1).Value = Replacement
        End If
    End With
    Go_to_next_input_row:  
Next K

End Sub
```

Comment: It seems like you have not finished adding context to your question. What is the problem and what is the question here?

Comment: It's unclear from your code what's on which sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly: for each Cell in H2:H98, you're looking for a match in A2:A98. It won't necessarily be on the same row. If you find a match in Column A, you want to take the value from Column B and put it in Column I on the same row as the search value we just looked for. In this case, this code will work:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Test()

Dim ws          As Worksheet
Dim srcRng      As Range        '' Source range
Dim schRng      As Range        '' Search range
Dim c           As Range
Dim search      As Range

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
Set srcRng = ws.Range("H2:H98")
Set schRng = ws.Range("A2:A98")

For Each c In srcRng     '' Iterate through your source range
    Set search = schRng.Find(c.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, SearchDirection:=xlNext)     '' Find the value from column H in column A
    If Not search Is Nothing Then
        c.Offset(, 1).Copy search.Offset(, 1)   '' Get the value from column B, from the same row as the value it found in column A
                                                '' Then paste that value in column I, on the same row as the value we searched for from column H
    End If
Next c
```

GoTo statements are generally (**generally, not always**) very, **very** bad practice. Especially in this kind of situation. You don't need them, it just makes your code convoluted.

Comment: The data I get with the updates are not in any order or complete they will send me like 6 updates for times in one email then another 6 in another so thats why I used the find function.  But I did use the For k = 2 to 98 and it did speed up the macro a lot.  But it loops still infinatly.

Comment: Its not letting me post the code in comments but where it loops is it goes to "If rngTmp is Nothing Then GoTo Next input row: then goes to Next K then just keeps cycling

Comment: I was able to mod my original code to what I changed it to with your input

Comment: Ok, so let me understand what you're trying to do. For each value in Column H, you want to see if there is a match in Column A, anywhere. If a match in Column A is found, it takes the value from Column B on that row, and puts it in Column I on the same row for that value you just searched for from Column H. Correct?

Comment: Close, and sorry for the confusion its hard for me to enter code/a sanatized example.

For each value in Column H it sees if there is a match in Column A, anywhere.  If a match in Column A is found it takes the value from I and copies it over B on the row.

Comment: EX: Column A has names and on A32 the name is Bob next to him in B32 is his time 12:30.  I import updated times and put them in H:I so H2 has Bob and I2 has 10:30 I want the macro to copy 10:30 over 12:30